# Behavior of sum() with NAs

Tags: r

I have a series of numbers I need to sum some values are missing(=NA), in some rare cases all values are missing. For example:

```
sum(c(1,1,2),na.rm=TRUE)
sum(c(1,1,NA),na.rm=TRUE)
```

The first line evaluates to 4 the second to 2.

However, if all cases are NA as in:

```
sum(c(NA,NA,NA),na.rm=TRUE)
```

This evaluates to 0, and not NA.

Ideally, if all values are NA I would like this to evaluate to NA. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define our own sum function:

```
my_sum <- function(...) sum(..., na.rm = !all(is.na(c(...))))
```

**Result:**

```
> my_sum(c(NA, 1))
[1] 1
> my_sum(c(NA, 1, 2))
[1] 3
> my_sum(c(NA, NA))
[1] NA
> my_sum(c(NA, 1), 1)
[1] 2
> my_sum(c(NA, NA), NA)
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ifelse` like this:

```
some_vector <- c(1,2,3,NA)
ifelse(sum(is.na(some_vector)) == length(some_vector), NA, sum(some_vector, na.rm = TRUE))
```